# WPF scroll multiline textbox to caret position

Tags: wpf, scroll, textbox, multiline, caret

today I'm searching for a way to scroll a multiline, dynamically sized textbox.

I want to scroll to the Caret and don't find any helpful informations at the internet.

After trying many things i know how to scroll to the end of a line, but not how to scroll to the caret.
The scroll to the right line is already implemented, but the horizontal scroll part is already missing.

```
 private void txtText_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            var CurrentLineIndex = txtText.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(((TextBox)sender).SelectionStart);
            txtText.ScrollToLine(CurrentLineIndex);
        }
       
 }
```

This is my current code, which does scrolling to the right line for me.

Tryed to do something simular for the horizontal scrolling:

```
var rect = ((TextBox)sender).GetRectFromCharacterIndex(((TextBox)sender).CaretIndex);
txtText.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Math.Max((txtText.HorizontalOffset + rect.Right - (txtText.ActualWidth - 40)), 0.0));
```

But it doesn't work like expected, it scrolls not to the horizontal caret position.

**Think, i had to discribe it better:**

if i move the caret with the left or right arrow, it will work fine without implementing anything.

It doesn't work if i do this:

Move from one line to another.
Sometimes one of these lines is longer or shorter than another and at this case i had to scroll to the caret position.

***Example:***

Line1 is longer than line2

I navigate with the key "end" at the keyboard to the end of line1.

Then i navigate to to line2.

It all works correctly, the caret jumps to the end of line2 and it will scrolls automatically into visibile area.

But if i go back from line2 to line1 the caret is position right at the end of line1. But it scrolls not to the end of line1.

Comment: I am pretty sure that what you want is the default behavior already. By default the `TextBox` will scroll to the end of the line when *End* key was previously pressed.  
Also by default the `TextBox` will move the caret to the next/previous line on key down/up. By default the caret position is scrolled into view. Your manual line scrolling is breaking this behavior. I also doubt that your code is actually doing what you think it does. Before your code executes the `TextBox` has already handled the key events.

Comment: If you would mark the event as handled, you may realize that your code is really doing nothing. Obviously `TextBox` is ultimately build around key events - it's a text input control. There is a lot of key press handling going on and most event handling is actually deferred, resulting in client handler actions being overwritten. I wonder why you think you need to re-implement keyboard handling for the `TextBox`.

Comment: yes, i thought too that this is standard handled for a textbox.
But it seems to be, that is not that easy.
Seems that all these nice behaviours are only functioning if a textbox has a fixed size.
Read at some articles, that the scrollviewer not can handle the dynamically size of a element.
As i know there is one used in the textbox (not from me, but by definition), i thought that should be the problem.
Without my handling for the Down- and Up-Arrow the textbox will not scroll to the right line.

Comment: i found the problem. 
Didn't thought, that a style template can affect such strange behaviours - even if it is basedOn these element and the default style is not overwriten.
Because i had a rounded textbox i had to modify the scrollbars too. 
Want to do this with a style template for the scrollviewer. 
These ended at this strange behaviours.
Now i only use a Template for the Scrollbars and it will work fine...

Therefore solved - at a other way i thinked, but it worked....

would marked it as solved, but doesn't find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i used a Style template and forgot a necessary thing:

to pass

```
 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
```

to the ScrollContentPresenter.

After doing this, the standard behaviour will work well!